# Rails: update existing has_many through record via controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, updates, has-many-through

So two thirds of this works. Every time a User reads an Article, a History record is created (has_many through), which just says "User read Article at Read_Date_X".

The database is ok, the models are ok, the read_date param is permitted in the History controller, and the following operation works both 1) to check if a User has read an article before and 2) to create a new History record if it is the first time on this article.

But I cannot work out why the middle bit (to just update the read_date on an existing record) is not working. It doesn't matter if I try it with h.save! or h.update().

```
h = History.where(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user)
if h.exists?
  h = History.where(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user)
  h.read_date = Time.now
  h.save!
else
  h = History.new
  h.article_id = @article.id
  h.user_id = current_user.id
  h.read_date = Time.now
  h.save!
end
```

The error it throws if it finds an existing record is:

```
undefined method `read_date=' for #<History::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe7f30a5e50>
```

**UPDATE: working answer**

So Derek was right, and this version works. The middle bit needed a single instance, not an array, which is what the top conditional (without .first) was checking for. Using that to return a single record, though, means you need to swap "exists?" to "present?" in the second part.

```
h = History.where(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user).first
if h.present?
  h.read_date = Time.now
  h.save!
else
  h = History.new
  h.article_id = @article.id
  h.user_id = current_user.id
  h.read_date = Time.now
  h.save!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`History.where(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user)` is returning a `History::ActiveRecord_Relation`. If you want to set the read_date, you'll want to get a single record.

Here's one way you could do this with what you have currently:

```
h = History.where(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user).first
```

Another way you could handle this is by using `find_by` instead of `where`. This would return a single record. Like this:

```
h = History.find_by(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user)
```

However, if it's possible for a user to have many history records for an article, I would stick to the way you're doing things and make one change. If for some reason you have a lot of history records, this may not be very efficient though.

```
histories = History.where(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user)
histories.each { |history| history.update(read_date: Time.now) }
```

Comment: Yes that was it, well done Derek. Also, can't use "exists?" with a single instance but you can with the Relation array. Will post the working version.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is already answered. Here are a couple of additional thoughts and suggestions.

- I would not have a separate `read_date` attribute. Just use `updated_at` instead. It's already there for you. And, the way your code works, `read_date` and `updated_at` will always be (essentially) the same.
- When looking up whether the history exists, you can do `current_user.histories.where(article: @article)`. IMO, that seems cleaner than: `History.where(article_id: @article, user_id: current_user).first`.
- You can avoid all that `exists?` and `present?` business by just checking if the `h` assignment was successful. Thus, `if h = current_user.histories.where(article: @article)`.
- If you go the route of using `updated_at` instead of `read_date`, then you can set `updated_at` to `Time.now` by simply doing `h.touch`.
- I would use the `<<` method provided by `has_many :through` (instead of building the `history` record by hand). Again, if you use `updated_at` instead of `read_date`, then you can use this approach.

So, you could boil your code down to:

```
if h = current_user.histories.where(article: @article)
  h.touch 
else 
  current_user.articles << @article 
end
```

You *could* use a ternary operator instead of that `if then else`, in which case it might look something like:

```
current_user.histories.where(article: @article).tap do |h|
  h ? h.touch : current_user.articles << @article 
end
```

Comment: Thanks @jvillian, that's kind of you. Had found "touch" already and got rid of read_date, but didn't know you could use << on has_many relations directly like that. I'll give it a go.